# weird collision probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Suppose we have total $n$ lists, each of them contain $c_i$ elements, which are from 1 to $c_i$. I want to store them in the following way:

We have a large two-dimension $N*C$ array $A$. For each list $l_i$ of $n$ lists, firstly, randomly choose index $r_i$ of $N$. Then, for list $l_i$, storing its $c_i$ elements in the first $c_i$ slots of $A[r_i]$. But the bad thing is, later on, when another list $l_j$ is assigned to the same slot $r_i$, collision happens and we counter the collision is $min(c_i, c_j)$.

We denote total elements of $n$ lists is $q=\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i$ and all $c_i < C$. I want to calculate the collision probability, and want to see whether the collision is negligible to $N*C$ if $N=exp(\lambda) $, $n=poly(\lambda)$, $q=poly(\lambda)$ and $C=poly(\lambda)$.

Comment: So wait, here $N=n$ ? And $C = \max_i c_i$ ? 
So you basically have a grid in which we have, in theory, enough space to store every list $l_i$ if we were to assign them to each column of the grid separately ? However we choose the column randomly, hence the collisions ?
Or is your grid funamentally too small to contains every element of all $l_i$ ?
Also if I understood well, each list $l_i = [1,2,..., c_i]$ ?
Sorry but your question is not really clear to me.

Comment: @Zubzub sorry for the unclear, $n=poly(\lambda) \ll N$, and $max_i c_i \leq C$. yes we have enough space to store every list but only assign them to the column randomly.

Comment: What do you define as a collision ? Basically as soon as an index $r$ is randomly drawn twice, we will have a collision. The part of your question with "$min(c_i,c_j)$" in not really clear. I understand that it means that in case of collision with $l_i,l_j$ then exactly $min(c_i,c_j)$ element will be overridden but do we count that as $1$ collision or $min(c_i,c_j)$ collisions ?

Comment: @Zubzub In case of collision $l_i,l_j$, $min(c_i, c_j)$ collisions are countered(after that, if list $l_k$ comes to the same index $r$ again, another $min(max(l_i,l_j),l_k)$ are countered). The total  space(all possibilities) is $N*C$, but for the same column $r$, the elements in $l_i$ are not distributed uniformly, because we always store a list form $A[r][0]$ to $A[r][c_i]$  .